# Find the sets $A \cup B $, $B^c$, and $(A\cap B)^c$ where $A,B,C$ are given intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let the universal set be the set $\mathbb{R}$ of all real numbers and let
>
> $A=\{x ∈ \mathbb{R}|−3≤ x ≤0\}$, $B=\{x∈\mathbb{R}|−1<x<2\}$,  $C = \{x ∈ \mathbb{R} | 6 < x ≤ 8\}$

I am supposed to find the sets $A \cup B $,  $B^c$, and $(A\cap B)^c$. I did this,  I am not sure if I'm solving correctly:

#### My solution

a) $A \cup B = \{x ∈ \mathbb R | x ∈ [−3, 0] \text { or } x ∈ (-1, 2)\} = \{x ∈\mathbb R | x ∈ [−3, 3)\} = [−3, 2)$.

f) $B^c =\{x ∈\mathbb R \mid \text{ is not the case that }x ∈(−1, 2)\}
= \{x ∈ \mathbb R|\text{ it is not the case that }(−1 < x\text{ and }x < 2)\} 
=\{x ∈\mathbb R|x ≤−1 \text { or }x \ge 2\}=(−∞, −1]∪[2, ∞)$

i) $(A\cap B)^c= \{x ∈\mathbb R| \text{ is not the case that }x ∈[−3, 2)\}= \{x ∈ \mathbb R| \text{ it is not the case that }(−3 \le x\text{ and }x < 2)\} 
=\{x ∈ \mathbb R \mid x <−3\text{ or }x \ge 2\}=(−∞, −3)∪[2, ∞)$

thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you specify it a little more? I cannot understand your question

Comment: What does $A\cup B\ \{-3,...,0\}$ mean?

Comment: I need to solve: A∪B , B^c,  (A∩B)^c taking into account following condition: Let the universal set be the set R of all real numbers and let A={x ∈ R|−3≤ x ≤0}, B={x∈R|−1<x<2}, and C = {x ∈ R | 6 <x ≤ 8}

Comment: I have edited my previous answers for a, f and i and think they are correct now, as I have misunderstood the question of the exercises myself first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See at the definitions of the sets you are looking for.

For example $x \in A \cup B \leftrightarrow x \in A \lor x \in B$.

$x \in A \cap C \leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge x \in C$.

So, let's find $A \cap C$.

$$A=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}| -3 \leq x \leq 0 \}$$
$$C=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}| 6<x \leq 8 \}$$

$$x \in A \cap C \leftrightarrow -3 \leq x \leq 0 \wedge 6<x \leq 8 $$

We  see that we cannot find such a $x$ since it would have to be at both the intervals $[-3,0]$ and $(6,8]$, that is impossible.

Thus, $A \cap C=\varnothing$.